# Upload Failed : The file was not uploaded because the path was not found on the server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Users are unable to save a file (Office documents) after changes were made to sharepoint. They get an error message "Upload Failed: The file was not uploaded because the path was not found on the server". When the document is reopened from the same location it shows the changes but opens with the same error message on top.

---

Verified Users have permissions to upload documents. Upload center is working but with following errors. The log viewer shows some errors as well.
[image: Upload Center and Log Viewer]

Comment: What were the changes you made to SharePoint?

Answer (score 2):

I've also seen this behavior if the SQL Server database runs out of diskspace.  The site will seem to work OK in 'read-only' mode, but any updates fail with the generic error message "Upload Failed: The file was not uploaded because the path was not found on the server".

Answer (score 1):

a couple of points to look into -

1. Check if users have the required permissions for file uploads
2. [Upload Center](http://sp2010solutions.blogspot.com/2012/04/office-upload-center.html) working (presuming SP 2010 installation)
3. Use [SP ULS Log Viewer](http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/) (or [another viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/458052/ULS-Log-Viewer)) to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error in my environment. Was able to resolve by restarting the WebClient service.

Start | Search for =>  Computer Management.

In Computer Management | Services and Applications |  Services | WebClient | Stop then Restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to resolve this issue by looking into IIS for SharePoint Server 2016

1. Go to IIS
2. Click on the SharePoint WebApplication
3. Then Click on _vti_bin folder
4. Check the Authentication Settings for _vti_bin
5. Enable --> Anonymous Authentication, ASPNET, Forms and Windows Authentication

Hope this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when we tried to save changes to the Docs (Word,Excel) also when tried to edit the file after opening in excel once after disabling the Anonymous Authentication of the site in IIS.

And it got resolved when reverted.

Brgds
Hafzal